# Postgres sum, consider NaN value as 0

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, nan

I have a table with a column name value like this:

```
value
===
1.0
4.7
'NaN'
0
```

Some of rows may have NaN value.
I need sum(value) consider NaN value as 0, something like `SELECT sum(isnull(value,0))` but for NaN value. Is there something like that for NaN value?

Comment: Column data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **nulliff** as below

```
select sum(nullif(value, 'NaN'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select sum(case when value <> 'NaN' then value end)
```

This treats `NaN` as `NULL`, which is ignored in a `SUM()`.  You can of course add `else 0` if you prefer `0`.